# Extraction issue with bold heading letters from pdf using tika

Tags: python, apache-tika, pdf-extraction

I am new with reading text from pdf using python. I am using tika to extract content from pdf, and when it extracts bold headings, it seems to fail.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKJM.png)

In the example above, it's reads "Rating the Items" as following "RRaattiinngg  tthhee  IItteemms" and this happens with other headings as well, is it something to do with library I am using or the issue is with pdf itself.

Code I am using:

```
from tika import parser
raw=parser.from_file(config.PATH)
print(raw['content']
```

Are there better library for extracting text from pdf?

Thank You

Comment: I can not upload the PDF as it contains confidential information.

Comment: Tried that it didn't show any doubled letters. Also, opened the pdf using word, it didn't show any  doubling letter.